# Excel work? How to copy and do multiple post with a numeral change.?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I got his line on excel:

C:\Users\JP\Desktop\Stuff\Pictures\Pistons.JPG

I need to replicate the line 100 times changing the picture name at the end like.

xxxx\Pistons1.JPG
xxxx\Pistons2.JPG
xxxx\Pistons3.JPG

etc..

Would anybody know a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In `A1`, put this formula:

```
="C:\Users\JP\Desktop\Stuff\Pictures\Pistons" & row() & ".JPG"
```

Then drag down.

Comment: Thank you, that surely put the number down..

Comment: Thank you, that surely put a number down.

But now I have another problem with it ☹  Maybe I should mention everything I want to do.

I want to  create something like:

Pistons1.jpg
Pistons2.jpg
Pistons3.jpg

Shaft1.jpg
Shaft2.jpg
Shaft3.jpg

Then… combine it like:

Pistons.1jpg
Shats1.jpg
Piston2.jpg
Shafts2.jpg
Pistons3.jpg
Shafts3.jpg

Comment: @Jim - That's a new question, if the Answer helped with the naming, then this question has the answer...if you have further questions, please start a new question.